# Sobrescrevi uma segue em swift, preciso sobrescrever todas depois?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Sobrescrevi algumas segues para usarem uma viewController, onde essa será dinâmica e recebendo o conteúdo de acordo com o menu clicado. Porém as outras segues que não coloquei um "identificador" pararam de funcionar.

Abaixo está um exemplo de como estou sobrescrevendo a segue.

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        escondeMenu()
        let viewControllerDestino = segue.destination as! CoringaViewController

        if segue.identifier == "mEvento" {
            viewControllerDestino.recebidoEventos = "Eventos"
```

Vou ter que colocar um identificador em todas as outras segues que pararam ?

Answer (score 1):

O método se aplica para todas as segues, o que você deve fazer é tratar para modificar apenas o segue que você deseja. Você não especificou o que seria "pararam de funcionar", nesse caso pode ser um crash onde o controller de destino não é um `CoringaViewController`, o que pode ser resolvido assim:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    escondeMenu()

    if segue.identifier == "mEvento", let viewControllerDestino = segue.destination as? CoringaViewController {
        viewControllerDestino.recebidoEventos = "Eventos"
    }
}
```